# Extract attributes from the original dataframe used to create a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
             sales
2015-10-05  -0.462626
2015-10-06  -0.540147
2015-10-07  -0.450222
2015-10-08  -0.448672
2015-10-09  -0.451773
... ...
2019-10-16  -0.594413
2019-10-17  -0.620770
2019-10-18  -0.586660
2019-10-19  -0.586660
2019-10-20  -0.671934
11340 rows × 1 columns
```

which I turn into a `tf.data.Dataset` like so:

```
data = np.array(df)
ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    data=data,
    targets=None,
    sequence_length=4,
    sequence_stride=1,
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=1,)
```

The dataset gives me records looking as such

```
print(next(iter(ds)))
tf.Tensor(
[[[-0.4626256 ]
  [-0.54014736]
  [-0.4502221 ]
  [-0.44867167]]], shape=(1, 4, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Which I use for training my ML model, however, I need a way of finding the dates corresponding to the values I fetch from the dataset. Using the example fetch from the dataset above, I want to find the dates corresponding to those consecutive values, which from the dataframe we can see is `[2015-10-05, 2015-10-06, 2015-10-07, 2015-10-08]`. Ideally, I would like to get other attributes as well if the dataframe has several columns. Is there a way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using another dataset as a lookup. That way you can add further attributes if needed:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': ['2015-10-05', '2015-10-06', '2015-10-07', '2015-10-08', '2015-10-09', '2019-10-16', '2019-10-17', '2019-10-18', '2019-10-19', '2019-10-20'],
                        'sales': [-0.462626, -0.540147, -0.450222, -0.448672, -0.451773, -0.594413, -0.620770, -0.586660, -0.586660, -0.671934]})


data = np.array(df['sales'])
ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    data=data,
    targets=None,
    sequence_length=4,
    sequence_stride=1,
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=1,)

d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df['date'].to_numpy())).batch(1)
dates = d.flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices).window(4, shift=1, stride=1).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(4)).batch(1)
d = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dates, ds))

def lookup(tensor, dataset):
  dataset = dataset.filter(lambda x, y: tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(y, tensor)))
  return [x.numpy().decode('utf-8') for x in list(dataset.map(lambda x, y: tf.squeeze(x, axis=0)))[0]]

result = lookup(next(iter(ds)), d)
print(result)
```

```
['2015-10-05', '2015-10-06', '2015-10-07', '2015-10-08']
```

Comment: Unfortunately not as I believe your `lookup` function returns the dates of all rows which have sales equal to ONE of the values in the dataset iteration. However, I want the dates only of the records in the dataframe where all consecutive values correspond to the values in the dataset iteration. For example, if there were an additional record with the `sales`  values of `-0.462626` in the end of the dataframe, I wouldn't want the date of that record to be returned as well.

Comment: @HaakonFlaar see updated answer

Comment: Works well! I guess this could also be done using a dictionary with values cast to a comma-separated string as key and a list of dates as values (or a dictionary with multiple attributes if required). It can however fail if the float numbers in the dictionary are slightly different than those in the tf dataset.